# Extract all n-element sequences from a list

Tags: python, sequence

How do I extract all n-element sequences from a list? Example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

```
assert f(a,1) == [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]
assert f(a,2) == [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
assert f(a,3) == [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
assert f(a,4) == [[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
assert f(a,5) == [[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

What is the fastest implementation of `f`?

Comment: These are not all n-element sequences if I'm not mistaken. For example in the second assertion you are skipping a (1,3) set. If you want to achieve exactly what your example shows, it's just loops, otherwise have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: Well, in case you want to achieve exactly what your example shows, you can use this: `f = lambda a, n: [a[index:index+n] for index in range(0, len(a) - n + 1)]`

Comment: @KacperFloriański each assert line is for a different n. The list comprehension you supplied is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic `zip` usage

```
def f(a, n):
    return list(zip(*[a[i:] for i in range(n)]))
```

Comment: One of your `n`s should probably be an `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it using a *generator function*, which will `yield` sequential slices from the list until there are none left of the required length:

```
def f(x, k, i = 0):
    while len(x[i : i+k]) == k:
        yield x[i : i+k]
        i += 1
```

**Usage**

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]

list(f(a, 1))
#[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]

list(f(a, 2))
#[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

list(f(a, 3))
#[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```